# JdbcPagingItemReader in Spring batch is not giving correct results

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-batch

I am facing issue that records return from *query* and *pagination* config i made giving incorrect no's of records. Is pagination config incorrect.
pagination return less no of records.

### Query equivalent of paging config

`select *
from SOME_TABLE 
where CLIENT_FILE_NM= 'process_abc.20150617024850'  AND TXN_ID IS NOT NULL AND SOME_DATA IS NOT NULL order by CREATE_DT ASC;`

### Paging config

```
     <bean id="postItemReader"
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader"
                scope="step">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                <property name="queryProvider">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
                        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                        <property name="selectClause" value="select *" />
                        <property name="fromClause" value="from SOME_TABLE" />
                        <property name="whereClause"
                            value="CLIENT_FILE_NM= :fileName AND TXN_ID IS NOT NULL AND SOME_DATA IS NOT NULL" />
                        <property name="sortKey" value="CREATE_DT" />
                        <!-- CARD_SETTL_STG_ID_PK ASC -->
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="parameterValues">
                    <map>
                        <entry key="fileName" value="#

{jobParameters['fileName']}" />
                    </map>
                </property>
                <property name="pageSize" value="10" />
                <property name="rowMapper">
                    <bean class="com.wdpr.payment.batch.mapper.OutputVOMapper" />
                </property>
                <property name="saveState" value="false"/>
            </bean>
```

Comment: What kind of db are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue got resolved as sortKey has to be unique key. Spring create query in below format :
`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM CRD_SETTL WHERE CLIENT_FILE_NM= :fileName AND TXN_ID IS NOT NULL AND SETTL_DATA IS NOT NULL ORDER BY CREATE_DT ASC) WHERE ROWNUM <= 10 AND ((CREATE_DT > :_CREATE_DT))`

and records will be missed.

`<property name="sortKey" value="CREATE_DT" />` // this was not unique ...

Comment: Any idea why `OraclePagingQueryProvider` API only fetches the 10 records by default ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your data on the database. I think the problem is related to the IS NOT NULL comparisons, depending on your database engine and table definitions NULL can be interpreted in different ways. Try to compare  TXN_ID != '', or > 0 depending on your data type.

Comment: Thanks i tried as u suggest. but it didn't work. any other suggestion u have